# isPrime Method is giving multiple responses, when I'm only looking for one?

Tags: java, methods

I can run this code perfectly, but it's not running as intended. I tried to make a isPrime Method, but I keep getting an error where I get multiple responses instead of the intended single response.

For example, if I put in the number 3, I'll get the response:

> [number] isn't prime.
>
> [number] is prime.

If I put the number 100, I'll get the response:

> [number] isn't prime.
>
> [number] isn't prime.
>
> [number] isn't prime.
>
> ...
>
> [number] is prime.

I'll get the "isn't prime." response 99 times and the 100th response will be "is prime." Every once in a while the response "is prime" will show up.

Could anyone let me know what's messing it up?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chapter_8_13 {


  public static void main(String[] args){  
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("This program helps determine if a number is prime!");
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int num = keyboard.nextInt();

    for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++)
    {
      if (num % i == 0)
      {
        System.out.println(num + " is prime.");
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println(num + " isn't prime.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your algorithm is wrong. Condition `if (num % i == 0)` says only that `num` divides by `i` (and `num` is not prime).

It should be:

```
boolean isPrime = true;
for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++)
    {
      if (num % i == 0)
      {
        isPrime = false;
        break;
      }
    }
if (isPrime) {
    System.out.println("is prime");
} else {
    System.out.println("isn't prime");
}
```

Comment: I would personally take the square-root of num, due to that being the most efficient way to check.

Comment: @RyenNelsen what's the problem? I already have square root in the code.

Comment: Thank you so much! I saw few examples online that had booleans in other places, but I haven't learned much yet. Sadly, my knowledge is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

You set a flag when `num` is divisible by any `i`. Then check the value of flag outside loop to find if its prime or not

```
flag=0;
for (int i = 2; i < num; i++)
{
      if (num % i == 0)
      {
        flag=1;
        break;
      }
}

if(flag==1)
    System.out.println(num + " is prime.");
else
  System.out.println(num + " isn't prime.");
```

NOTE: You need not loop `num` times. `sqrt(num)` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out
                .println("This program helps determine if a number is prime!");
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int num = keyboard.nextInt();

        boolean isPrime = true;

        for (int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                System.out.println(num + " isn't prime.");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime)
            System.out.println(num + " is prime.");
    }
}
```